# Partial derivatives and composition with matrices

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Given $f$ and $g$ are each functions sending $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$, if you know that

$$ [Df]_{(0,0)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

and

$$ [D(f \circ g)]_{(0,0)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 4 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} $$

What is the derivative of $g$ at $(0,0)$?

I believe the strategy is to replace two elements in the equation below (recognizing that $g$ and $f$ are switched from normal convention in the given problem):

$ [D(g \circ f)]_{a} = [Dg]_{f(a)} \cdot [Df]_{a} $

Via substitution, I get:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 4 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
? & ? \\
? & ? 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I don't know how to solve the unknown matrix from here.

In a more generalized sense, is there a way to find matrix A when AB = C and we know B and C? Or, is there another way to solve this problem?

I've only so far seen $Ax = b$ used when $x$ is a column vector. I tried to take the inverse of $A$ and multiply it with $C$, but reverse checking my work, that didn't work out.

(This is problem 2 in Robert Ghrist's textbook in multivariable calculus, volume 2, chapter 5.)

Comment: Where are the partial derivatives?

Comment: This book? https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/calculus.html

Comment: That's his webpage. The specific book can be found here: https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-BLUE-Multivariable-2-Derivatives-ebook/dp/B01BNSZG10/ref=sr_1_1?crid=110EM1IYBQPXD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the chain rule,

$$ D(f \circ g)(x) = Df(g(x)) Dg(x) $$

and since $g(0, 0) = (0, 0)$, we know $Df(0, 0)$ from the given. Now we need to find the matrix $U$ such that

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 4 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
U. $$

But matrix multiplication is just a linear combination of the columns! Denote the columns of $U$ by $u_1, u_2$. Let the matrix on the left be $B$, with columns $b_1, b_2$. Then you just need to solve the two systems

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} u_1 = b_1 $$

and $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} u_2 = b_2$$

which is an easy task. I leave the rest as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> I've only so far seen Ax=b used when x is a column vector. I tried to take the inverse of A and multiply it with C, but reverse checking my work, that didn't work out.

Why not?  You have the correct approach, and finding the inverse is just a matter of following the rule.

$\begin{align}\mathcal Df_{g(0,0)}\, \mathcal Dg_{(0,0)} &=\mathcal D[f\circ g]_{(0,0)}  &\qquad& A~B= C \\[2ex] \mathcal Dg_{(0,0)} &= (\mathcal Df_{(0,0)})^{-1}\,\mathcal D[f\circ g]_{(0,0)}&& B= A^{-1}\, C\\&=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-1 &4\\2&3\end{bmatrix}\\&=\dfrac 11\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1 &4\\2&3\end{bmatrix} &&\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\\c& d\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}=\tfrac{1}{ad-bc}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}~~~d & -b\\-c&~~~a\end{smallmatrix}\right]\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$

The rest is matrix multiplication.